# Is it possible to use a VM as driver?

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, raspbian

I want to use a wireless usb adapter for my raspberry pi 4 but there are only drivers available for windows. Since ndiswrapper does not work on a raspberry pi my second idea was to create a VM running windows that would function as a driver between the usb and the host OS(raspbian). I still haven't found the best way to execute this plan. My first idea was just to use port forwarding but I'm pretty sure that some applications won't function correctly using this method. Another approach of mine was to create a host-only network, a bridge or use NAT as a way to forward the traffic to the VM and then to the usb. If this works and you have any improvement ideas or any idea how to actually execute this then please share :)

Edit:

I have just realized that I have pretty much invented a router. So if my explanations were not understandable: I want to turn a VM into a router.

Comment: Can you run MS on the Pi? Is the driver available for this version of MS? Will you have enough RAM left over, to do the real work?

Comment: Using a VM like Virtual Box or VMWare won't probably work because I only have 4GBs of RAM. I was hoping that anyone here would have an idea on how to run windows with minimum effort. I have already looked into docker but apparently it is impossible to have a windows container.

Comment: Have you considered using an ethernet cable, or using the built in Wifi?

Comment: Yes but I am currently working on a project to make the pi a portable machine that doesn't need any peripherals like keyboard, mouse or monitor. And I want to set up a web IDE for development and a web interface where i can execute finished scripts. My plan was to turn the PI into an AP using the built in WIFI and another WIFI(the usb) as an antenna for packet capturing. But the USB had to have some technical difficulties so it will probably be easier to use it as the AP and route traffic between my PC and the Pi.